# How to Debug a web service

Tags: c#

We have a Win32 application that connects to a third party application to send some info to it. That application has a web service that we call its methods. One of its web methods is called GetDevices and when our application is calling it, it will fail to work and I have no idea what are the details of this failure. So we should write a small diagnosis application that can create some detailed log files to know what is going, send it to them to run it and then we may know what is going on with more detail. Now do you have any ideas what is a good way to write such a diagnosis application for this debugging purpose?

Comment: As @KirstenJones mentioned Using Fiddler will give you the HTTP error code. You should take a screenshot of fiddler and send it to the 3rd party vendor to fix the Web Service method. I wouldn't even bother with Fiddler I'd get on the phone and tell them.

Answer (score 2):

If this web service is using HTTP (either SOAP or REST) you can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to snoop the HTTP traffic and see what's happening.

When web requests are made, the request (and response from the server) will show up in Fiddler, and you can use that to determine why it's not doing what you expect.